# Why was letter 's' chosen as on option for human readable format in quota command?

Tags: quota

I often try to memorize command options by looking up for what they stand for.

This time I couldn't find any source on that: why is `quota -s` a `--human-readable` alternative, what does `s` stand for?

Comment: Funny. On BSD the `quota` option for "human-readable" is `-h` (then you would not ask).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the light shed from the FreeBSD version of the `quota` command, I would go for **suffixes** (my first choice being *string*).

```
     -h      "Human-readable" output.  Use unit suffixes: Byte, Kilobyte,
             Megabyte, Gigabyte, Terabyte and Petabyte.
```

Either way, all here are best guesses ...

Answer (score 2):

Slightly more informed guess. Looking into the `-s` options of various [coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Index) commands and their interpretation in those commands, it seems like `-s` is an option that can mean many different things in different commands. Following list shows meaning of the `-s` option for the commands in parenthesis:

- seconds (`sleep`)
- system (`uname`)
- setid (`chmod` (+/-))
- string (`nl`, `date`, `seq` )
- suffix (`cp`, `install`, `ln`, `mv`, `basename`)
- size (`sort`, `shred`, `truncate`, `test`)
- silent (`tty`, `readlink`, `csplit`)
- signal (`kill`, `timeout`)
- separator (`tac`, `pr`)
- summary (`du`)
- sysv (`sum`)
- skip-chars (`unique`)
- serial (`paste`)
- squeeze/suppress (`tr`, `cat`)
- symbolic/soft (`ln`)
- strip (`realpath`)
- spaces (`fold`)
- split (`fmt`)

From the list, it looks like suffix is frequently used in the context of filename suffixes, so I will go with **size**.

Interestingly, the description of `-s` in the man page of `ls` sounds close to what the author might have in mind while choosing the `-s` switch with `quota`:

> -s      Display the number of file system blocks actually used by each file, in units of 512 bytes, where partial units are rounded up to the next integer value.  If the output
>                is to a terminal, a total sum for all the file sizes is output on a line before the listing.  The environment variable BLOCKSIZE overrides the unit size of 512 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the man page I would conclude that it stands for "size" or "space" or "showing" or perhaps "suffixes". From the `quota` man page:

```
   -s, --human-readable
        option will make quota(1) try to choose units for showing limits, 
        used space and used inodes.
```